# C++ warning: virtual function override with unused arguments

Tags: c++

This is my 1st question posted on StackOverflow. I have come across a C++ warning to solve. The thing is we have overridden virtual functions in derived class, while there are a few function arguments not being used in the overridden function body. As a result, the compiler keeps warning. This is quite a common issue in my C++ project with class hierarchy. I have tried the following two solutions and both would work. Just wonder which one is more golden or widely used. Or if there is any other golden solution to this issue, please feel free to advise.

```
void f(int a) {} (WARNING) ==> void f(int a) { (void)a; } (NO WARNING)
void f(int a) {} (WARNING) ==> void f(int) {} (NO WARNING)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Third solution: `void f(int a [[maybe_unused]]) {}` ([C++ attribute reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes))

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think the attribute comes before the declaration.

Comment: And no there's really no "golden rule". It's just a matter of personal preference and style. You could, for example, make it a habit to not write the argument names when creating functions, not until you need that argument. That could be one way of solving this problem.

Comment: If your C++ version supports `[[maybe_unused]]` I'd use that.  Otherwise I'd prefer omit the parameter, and if that isn't do-able then `(void)` cast it.

Comment: @cigien Both seem to work. IIRC, if you put it on the left, it applies to all variables in a declaration, and if you put it after the name, it only applies to one. Doesn't matter here.

Comment: @cigien Some do, some don't, some might work both ways. I know that for arguments trailing `maybe_unused` attribute works for my code (using GCC 9 and 10) :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, cool, I did not know that, thanks.

Comment: I wonder if this is considered a 'bike shedding' question? I like it :)

Comment: Apart from techniques to suppress the warning, you might also want to revisit the design.   Generally speaking, a base class specifies virtual functions based on requirements that will be common to all derived classes.   If the base class is specifying a set of arguments for a virtual function that are not needed by one or more derived classes, that's often a big hint that some aspect hasn't been properly considered when designing the base class.

Comment: You said you are not using some of the parameters in the overridden method in the derived class. Do you own the base class ? If not, then adding attributes to mask warnings is fine, but if you own the base class as well, you should look into a better class design where the parameters are relevant and will be used. The [maybe_used] attributes are generally used when external library code is inherited and we don't use them and nor have control over them

Comment: @Peter i didn't expanded  your comment when posting mine, then realize that it's almost a duplicate. The only difference is to assert whether the base class is self owned code (or) from a library. Can you add that to your answer and i will delete mine.

Comment: @Soundararajan  Thanks for the advices! I am able to make changes to both base and derived classes. The root cause of the unused function parameters in derived class is that we to maximize code sharing between different utilities, so that it would be easier to maintain in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three (the third being `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute mentioned in the comments) are fine, and choice is purely aesthetic and subjective.

`(void)a` is least meaningful to me personally, but it has a long tradition, and some other cases of unused names don't have the same option of leaving out the name as an argument does, so it may be the only option (in previous versions of the language where `[[maybe_unused]]` did not yet exist).